# Erasing a line in vector which includes specific character

Tags: c++11

I am doin c++ homework for my school and my vector has an element which is like:

"00026324 John Adams, -1" i need to delete the element completely if it includes -1 as a string so how can i erase it from the vector. By the way i can't upload my code because of plagiarism issues. Thank you

Comment: For those (like me) who needed to translate [plagiarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism).

Comment: Uploading *your* code can not be plagiarism. Plagiarism means that you use someone else's work (or your own work multiple times), and pretend that it is yours (original).

Comment: if someone from my school see the post and copy i will also plagiarised

Answer (score 0):

You must use the method `remove_if`. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdremove-stdremove_if-c/) is a documentation with an example.